# Call one procedure from another and use value that it returns MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have procedure `"GetCurrentUserRoleByDomainLogin"` that returns me UserRole.
And I want to execute this procedure in condition of another procedure (`GroupInsertUpdateDelete`), but it gives me syntax error.

This is "**GetCurrentUserRoleByDomainLogin":**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCurrentUserRoleByDomainLogin]
AS

SELECT UserRole FROM [User]
JOIN Role on [User].UserRole=Role.RoleId
WHERE [User].DomainLogin = (SELECT SYSTEM_USER)
```

This is "**GroupInsertUpdateDelete:**"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GroupInsertUpdateDelete]
    @GroupName nvarchar(50),
    @GroupRole nvarchar(50),
    @StatementType nvarchar(50),    
    @UserRole nvarchar(50) = CALL GetCurrentUserRoleByDomainLogin

    AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE GroupName=@GroupName)
    PRINT 'Group with such GroupName already exists'

ELSE
IF @StatementType = 'Insert' AND @UserRole = 'Admin'
BEGIN
    insert into [Group]
       (GroupName,RoleName)
    values (@GroupName, @GroupRole)
    PRINT 'Group was added successfully'
    END

IF @StatementType = 'Update' AND @UserRole = 'Admin'
BEGIN
    UPDATE [Group]
    SET GroupName = @GroupName,
        GroupRole = @GroupRole      
        WHERE GroupName = @GroupName
        PRINT 'Group was updated successfully'
        END

IF @StatementType = 'Delete' AND @UserRole = 'Admin'
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [Group] WHERE GroupName = @GroupName
    PRINT 'Group was deleted successfully'
    END

IF @StatementType = 'Select'
BEGIN
    SELECT * from [Group]
    END
```

This string gives me syntax error:

```
@UserRole nvarchar(50) = CALL GetCurrentUserRoleByDomainLogin
```

So, to make it nice I want to call "GetCurrentUserRoleByDomainLogin" procedure in  "GroupInsertUpdateDelete" procedure and put the value it returns in variable and then check the value of last one in "if statement". How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must edit your SP to add OUTPUT parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCurrentUserRoleByDomainLogin]
    @UserRole nvarchar(50) OUTPUT
AS

SELECT TOP 1 @UserRole = UserRole 
FROM [User] u
INNER JOIN [Role] r
   ON u.UserRole = r.RoleId
WHERE u.DomainLogin = (SELECT SYSTEM_USER)

RETURN;
```

Then call it like:

```
DECLARE @UserRole nvarchar(50)

EXEC GetCurrentUserRoleByDomainLogin @UserRole OUTPUT
```

After that you can use `@UserRole` in your SP.

Answer (score 0):

CALL isn't a command in SQL Server.  Instead we have EXECUTE or EXEC.   And I don't think you can do it as a default value of the parameter.   Do it in the first line of code instead.

Answer (score 0):

you must set a `OUTPUT` parameter like the example in this page
[Return Data from a Stored Procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx)

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('Sales.uspGetEmployeeSalesYTD', 'P') IS NOT NULL
        DROP PROCEDURE Sales.uspGetEmployeeSalesYTD;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE Sales.uspGetEmployeeSalesYTD
@SalesPerson nvarchar(50),
@SalesYTD money OUTPUT
AS  

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @SalesYTD = SalesYTD FROM Sales.SalesPerson AS sp JOIN HumanResources.vEmployee AS e ON e.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID WHERE LastName = @SalesPerson;
RETURN
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCurrentUserRoleByDomainLogin]
  @UserRole NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
AS

SELECT UserRole FROM [User]
JOIN Role on [User].UserRole=Role.RoleId
WHERE [User].DomainLogin = SYSTEM_USER
GO
```

To use the above do the following:-

```
DECLARE @MyUserRole NVARCHAR(50)
EXEC [dbo].[GetCurrentUserRoleByDomainLogin] @MyUserRole OUTPUT
```

To be honest my preference would be to refactor the 2nd stored proc.  That way there is no argument that can be forced in to assume the role.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GroupInsertUpdateDelete]
    @GroupName nvarchar(50),
    @GroupRole nvarchar(50),
    @StatementType nvarchar(50)

    AS

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE GroupName=@GroupName)
    PRINT 'Group with such GroupName already exists'

ELSE

    BEGIN
        IF @StatementType = 'Select'
            BEGIN
                SELECT * from [Group]
            END     
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @UserRole nvarchar(50)
                SELECT UserRole 
                FROM [User]
                    INNER JOIN Role on [User].UserRole=Role.RoleId
                WHERE [User].DomainLogin = SYSTEM_USER


            IF @UserRole='Admin'
                BEGIN
                    IF @StatementType = 'Update'
                        BEGIN
                            UPDATE [Group]
                            SET GroupName = @GroupName,
                                GroupRole = @GroupRole      
                                WHERE GroupName = @GroupName
                                PRINT 'Group was updated successfully'
                        END
                    IF @StatementType = 'Insert'
                        BEGIN
                            insert into [Group]
                               (GroupName,RoleName)
                            values (@GroupName, @GroupRole)
                            PRINT 'Group was added successfully'
                        END
                    IF @StatementType = 'Delete' AND @UserRole = 'Admin'
                        BEGIN
                            DELETE FROM [Group] WHERE GroupName = @GroupName
                            PRINT 'Group was deleted successfully'
                        END
                END 
    END
GO
```

I have to say that I would advise against having a single proc to do this, particularly as it has something to do with the security of your application.

Someone who has access to execute this proc can do any CRUD they like on your Group.  I would strongly advise having a separation of duties here.
People who can read group information may not be the people who you'd want amending it.
Mechanically you can do it, but is it a good idea?